# Call functions dynamics of DLL's inside a Web Service C#

Tags: c#, web, dll, service

I have a Web Service called 'A'.

On this WS I want only stay looking the installed folder, in other words, together main DLL file.

On this directory I plan to put "modules" of my project and share the functions (Operation Contracts) with my WS.

For example:

ModuleOne.dll have the function:

```
string[] getUsersFromDatabase();
```

MyService.dll have the function:

```
object CallEventByName(string eventName, params string parameters);
```

And I imagine the use:

```
foreach string file in fileList
// Check if DLL file have the function equal to 'eventName',
// call the function passing your parameters if have
```

When I create the requisition SOAP, indicate the function name and the parameters. My WS need the intelligence to manage this requisition and return the "return" haha.

Who I can to this?

Comment: Use reflection to call the DLL functions from the WS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this , there may be a problem if dll which you want to load has dependencies , then you have load also this dll

```
    object CallFunction(string[] fileList , string eventName , object[] parameters){
        foreach(var file in fileList)
        {
            Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
            foreach(var t in assem.GetTypes())
            {
                var methodInfo = t.GetMethod(eventName);
                if(methodInfo != null)
                {
                    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                    return methodInfo.Invoke(obj , parameters);
                }    
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: how I can load an assembly with your dependencies?